# Sonar coverage is showing lesser than the actual

Tags: android, sonarqube, jacoco, sonarqube-scan

I have written test cases using JUnit and PowerMockito. IntelliJ IDEA is showing 100% coverage for lot many classes but Sonar is showing just 19%

I am using following versions:
PowerMockito: 2.0.2
JUnit: 4.12
Jacoco: 0.8.5
Sonar: 7.3

i have gone through multiple posts but nothing solved this issue.

Comment: Maybe you should inspect the coverage file that is send to SonarQube.

Comment: It got fixed by adding following block. Main issue was related to sonar was showing that few files are out of coverage due to some weird reason, like particular line is out of coverage but those lines were non-existing.                          jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.8.5"
    reportsDir = file("$buildDir/reports")
}

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you're running into the issue that Powermock replaces the Jacoco annotation during its instrumentation, so Jacoco has nothing to report against. You [may be able to change the instrumentation type](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Code-coverage-with-JaCoCo) to overcome this, but it's currently a know limitation when using Powermock.

Comment: I have written only non-instrument test cases

Comment: Do you have a project you can share that demonstrates the issue?